# Calling all functions with certain signature

Tags: powershell

I have a module (psm1 file), where I have a set of function. I need to call all functions in that module, which accept one parameter (an array of PSToken). Obviously, I can directly call all functions, but I need that changes in the module, didn't require changes in the calling script. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Get-Command` commandlet to iterate over the functions in a given module, and then call each function using dot-sourcing:

```
Import-Module MyPowershellModule

$arrPsToken = @($token1, token2, token3)

Get-Command -Module MyPowershellModule |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name |
    ForEach-Object {
        . "$_" $arrPsToken
    }
```

Keep in mind that this code assumes that all functions have the same signature, which is risky.

Comment: @levgen could use the `parameters` property of the returned functions to filter out the functions.